# post big image to facebook wall with facebook javascript api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

How can I post a big image along with my message to my facebook wall?
With the below code it only displays a min image?
And if I post a message and image from inside facebook, then that image is the full width of the timeline, how can I do that with the below code?

```
 function postonwall(){ 

         FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', 
             { 
                 message     : "testtext.",
                 link        : 'http://www.mydomain.se',
                 picture     : 'http://www.mydomain.se/image.jpg',
                 name        : 'somename',
                 description : 'sometext !'

         }, 
         function(response) {


             if (!response || response.error) {
                 alert('Error occured');
             } else {
                 //alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
               alert('Success: Content Published');
             }
         });
     }
```

Or what do I have to do to post a big image, if it doesnt work with this?
Any input appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've researched, the only way to post large images to a users wall/timeline is through the use of "User Generated Photos in the Open Graph"

Go here to learn more:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/